# Numpy - array of arrays recognize as vector

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, countvectorizer

I encounter a problem with numpy arrays.
I used **CountVectorizer** from sklearn with a wordset and values (from pandas column) to create an array of arrays that count words (BoW). And when I print the array and the shape, I have this result:

```
[[array([0, 5, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
 ...
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
 [array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]] (2800, 1)
```

An array of arrays having a vector shape ???

I checked that all rows have the same size.

Here is a way to reproduce my problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


data = pd.DataFrame(["blop blip blup", "bop bip bup", "boop boip boup"], columns=["corpus"])

# add labels column
data["label"] = ["blop", "bip", "boup"]

wordset = pd.Series([y for x in data["corpus"].str.split() for y in x]).unique()
cvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=wordset, ngram_range=(1, 2))
    
labels_count_np = data["label"].apply(lambda x: cvec.fit_transform([x]).toarray()[0]).values

print(labels_count_np, labels_count_np.shape)
```

it should return:

```
[array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])] (3,)
```

Can someone explain me why numpy has this comportment ?

Also, I tried to find a way to concatenate multiple arrays like this:

```
A = [array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])]
B = [array([0, 7, 2, 0]) array([1, 4, 0, 8])
 array([6, 1, 0, 9])]

concatenate(A,B) =>
[
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 8],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 0, 9]
]
```

But I did not found a good way to do it.

Comment: `np.hstack((A, B))` or `np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)` to concatenate

Comment: @Ali_Sh `np.hstack((A, B))` or `np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)` do not do what I want. If I use these functions, I will have the following shape (X, 2). I want to have this shape (X, A_column_shape + B_column_shape).

Comment: It seems that your results are a list of lists of arrays (one object/array in a list is still a list). The code that you share to reproduce the problem is output exactly what you write that it should, a list of arrays. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi My problem is that I can't answer to this question: "Why an array of arrays has (X, 1) shape ?" (eg. the first figuring example). You mentionned 'object'. Do the problem is that my array is an numpy array object ? I just want to understand this numpy comportment.

Comment: @AlexandreJuan, I did not understand what you want??? this modules will result in shape `(3, 13)`, which is `A_column_shape + B_column_shape` (e.g. 9 + 4) if A and B be array of arrays (e.g. if `A =np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])` and `B = np.array([[0, 7, 2, 0], [1, 4, 0, 8], [6, 1, 0, 9]])`. What do you want to know by *why numpy has this comportment ?* above this line is the problem (which works correctly) or below it? If the answer by hpaulj did not solve your problem, let me know. In your example it gets ndarray of ndarrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` from a dataframe, even if it has just one column, will be 2d.  `values` from a Series, one column of the frame, will be 1d.

If `labels_count_np` is (2800, 1) shape, you can easily make it 1d with `labels_count_np[:,0]` or `np.squeeze(labels...)`.  That's just basic `numpy`.

It will still be an object dtype array containing arrays, the elements of the dataframe cells.  If those arrays are all the same size then

```
 np.stack(labels_count_np[:,0])
```

should create a 2d numeric array.

Make a frame with array elements:

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame([None,None,None], columns=['x'])
In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
      x
0  None
1  None
2  None
In [37]: for i in range(3):df['x'][i] = np.zeros(4,int)
In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
              x
0  [0, 0, 0, 0]
1  [0, 0, 0, 0]
2  [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The 2d array from the frame:

```
In [39]: df.values
Out[39]: 
array([[array([0, 0, 0, 0])],
       [array([0, 0, 0, 0])],
       [array([0, 0, 0, 0])]], dtype=object)
In [40]: _.shape
Out[40]: (3, 1)
```

from the Series:

```
In [41]: df['x'].values
Out[41]: 
array([array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0])],
      dtype=object)
In [42]: _.shape
Out[42]: (3,)
```

Joining the Series values into one 2d array:

```
In [43]: np.stack(df['x'].values)
Out[43]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I already tried `np.squeeze` but it did not work but `np.stack` is perfectly what I searched ! Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate using list comprehension:

```
C = [np.append(x, B[i]) for i, x in enumerate(A)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0]), 
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 8]), 
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 0, 9])]
```

Comment: I found this solution great but the problem is that when I compute a lot of data, it seems to be very ressource intensive ! Does it exist a solution without iterating ? (I think it's the source of the computational problem)